# A simpler way to validate a tic tac toe board

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking there has to be an easier way to do this. Can anyone give me some suggestions? I'm validating a tic tac toe board and probably overthinking it.

```js
const checkSetForSingleValue = set => {
  if (set.size === 1) {
    let val = set.values().next().value;
    if  (val) return val;
  }
  return false;
};

const checkForWin = board => {
  let set, col, val;
  for (let i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
    set = new Set(board[i]);
    val = checkSetForSingleValue(set);
    if (val) return val;

    // we only need to loop through columns once
    if (i !== 0) continue;

    for (let j=0; j<board[i].length; j++) {
      set = new Set([board[0][j], board[1][j], board[2][j]]);
      val = checkSetForSingleValue(set);
      if (val) return val;
    }
  }

  // check for diagonal win
  if (board[1][1]) { // make sure center isn't null
    set = new Set([board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]]);
    val = checkSetForSingleValue(set);
    if (val) return val;

    set = new Set([board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]]);
    val = checkSetForSingleValue(set);
    if (val) return val;
  }

  return false;
};

let board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', null, null],
  ['o', 'o', 'x']
];

alert(checkForWin(board));

board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', 'x', null],
  ['x', 'o', 'x']
];

alert(checkForWin(board));
```

Comment: Looks good. Anyway, computations with matrtix 3x3 can affect nothing. Possibly your task can be resolved with math matrix magic, but I'm not so good in it. And, from my opinion, you should use `true-false-null` instead of `'x'-'o'-null`. In my case you should change your code little bit, because your checks will fail.

Answer (score 1):

**Validations for tic tac toe**
*Este codigo está hecho en c++*

```
bool vacio = false;
char jugadorEncontrado = tablero[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {

        jugadorEncontrado = tablero[i][j];
        //vertical and horizontal validations

        if ((tablero[i][0] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[i][1] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[i][2] == jugadorEncontrado) || (tablero[0][i] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[1][i] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[2][i] == jugadorEncontrado))
        {
            if (jugadorEncontrado == 'X')
            {
                return GANO_X;
            }
            else if (jugadorEncontrado == 'O')
            {
                return GANO_O;
            }
        }
        // diagonal validations
        if ((tablero[0][0] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[1][1] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[2][2] == jugadorEncontrado) || (tablero[2][0] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[1][1] == jugadorEncontrado && tablero[0][2] == jugadorEncontrado))
        {
            if (jugadorEncontrado == 'X')
            {
                return GANO_X;
            }
            else if (jugadorEncontrado == 'O')
            {
                return GANO_O;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {

        if (tablero[i][j] == '_')
        {
            vacio = true;
        }
    }
}

return vacio ? JUEGO_EN_CURSO : EMPATE;
```

Comment: The question was for [tag:javascript], not c++.  Thus this isn't an answer.

Comment: That's right brother, but I think that as programmers what we need the most sometimes is the logic of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We could generate a list of possible wins, e.g.

```
[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]] // [x,y]
```

So then we just need to iterate that once, and find a possible match. We can generate that easily like this (and may cache and minify):

```
var wins=[
 ...[0,1,2].map((y,_,row)=>row.map(x=>[x,y])),//vertical
 ...[0,1,2].map((x,_,row)=>row.map(y=>[x,y])),//horizontal
 ...[[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]],[[0,2],[1,1],[2,0]]]//diagonal
];
```

To check a board then simply iterate:

```
 board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', 'x', null],
  ['x', 'o', 'x']
 ];

var win=wins.find(win=>win.reduce((s,[x,y])=>s===board[x][y]?s:false,board[win[0][0]][win[0][1]]));
console.log(board[win[0][0]][win[0][1]]+" won");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think It's Very Simple, Just Check the valid condition ...

```
const checkForWin = board => {
    let flag = false;
    for (let i=0;i<3;i++){
            if((board[i][0] == 'o' && board[i][1] == 'o' && board[i][2] == 'o') || (board[0][i] == 'o' && board[1][i] == 'o' && board[2][i] == 'o')){
                return true;
            }
    }

    if((board[0][0] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o') || (board[2][0] == 'o' && board[1][1] == 'o' && board[0][2] == 'o')){
        return true;
    }

  return false;
};

let board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', null, null],
  ['o', 'o', 'x']
];

alert(checkForWin(board));

board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', 'x', null],
  ['x', 'o', 'x']
];

alert(checkForWin(board));
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @Chirag Goti's response...

```
const checkForWin = board => {
  let b = board;

  for (let i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
    if (b[i][0] && b[i][0] === b[i][1] && b[i][1] === b[i][2]) {
      return b[i][0];
    } else if (b[0][i] && b[0][i] === b[1][i] && b[1][i] === b[2][i]) {
      return b[i][0];
    }
  }

  if (b[1][1]) {
    if (b[0][0] === b[1][1] && b[1][1] === b[2][2] ||
        b[0][2] === b[1][1] && b[1][1] === b[2][0]) {
      return b[1][1];
    }
  }

  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A readable way is to enumerate the eight ways a player can win and test those.

```js
function winner(board) {
  const lines = [
    board[0], // rows
    board[1],
    board[2],
    [board[0][0], board[1][0], board[2][0]], // cols
    [board[0][1], board[1][1], board[2][1]], 
    [board[0][2], board[1][2], board[2][2]], 
    [board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]], // diags
    [board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]]
  ];
  const winningLine = lines.find(line => line.every(c => c && c === line[0]))
  return winningLine ? winningLine[0] : null
}

let board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', null, null],
  ['o', 'o', 'x']
];

console.log(winner(board));

board = [
  ['o', 'x', 'x'],
  ['o', 'x', null],
  ['x', 'o', 'x']
];

console.log(winner(board));
```